# Update a react project that uses firebase hosting

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

I used firebase hosting to serve my react website. If I want to make changes to my website, do I need to type `npm run build` every time after I change my local files so that a new build folder overlaps the old one and then type `firebase deploy`?

Answer (score 4):

You just have to run two commands.

1. `npm run build`
2. `firebase deploy`
   that's it. Then refresh your web page.

Comment: That is exactly what's proposed in the question, could you maybe explain further why both commands are needed?

Comment: Off course,  Actually,
1. npm run build 
is for compress the whole code into a static format 
for super fast running and convert other new version into Es5 version. cause many browser can't understand the new version of js.
And cause of without static version code, new change can't work parally(firebase policy in the case)

Comment: 2. After that, new change will be updated through,
firebase deploy
command.
Though firebase do not replace with new unbuild code with build static program, you can't get new code response in server.
 you have to build whole code before deploy on firebase. everytime.
'Deploy' is for update with replace old version of code.

Comment: Great! I meant to ask you to add the explanation to your answer though, because without it, it was not very helpful. However, you can augment it with what you wrote in the two comments!

Answer (score 1):

Do all your the changes in your React app. And run

1st Command- `npm run deploy`

2nd Command- `firebase deploy`

It's done.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is required.  If you don't generate and deploy new code and assets, nothing will change on your site.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to deploy firebase to cloud hosting every time you want to test it locally.
You can use `firebase serve --only hosting` to deploy on localhost.

`npm run build` depends entirely on your package.json, I'm not sure what your scripts look like.

However, I think your actually asking how to achieve hot reloading of your client during development. I don't remember ever having an issue achieving this using Create-React-App https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app which uses webpack.

The user guide details how to use `npm start` which should enforce hot-reloading: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts#npm-start

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Sorry that I did not make my question clear enough. Since I have deployed my project to my firebase, there is already a build folder in the project folder, as firebase deployed the content of the build folder. After I changed my local javascript files and ran "firebase serve," the changes did not show up. So I am wondering whether I need to type "npm run build" to "compile" the files into a new build project (which overlaps the old one) so that new changes are saved.

Answer (score 0):

It will work in 3 steps:

1. ```
   npm run build
   ```
2. ```
   firebase deploy
   ```
3. Refresh the page

Run the above commands and then refresh the page.